# TextButton.icon and ElevatedButton.icon: is it possible to show the label first then the icon?

Tags: flutter

I can't seem to find a parameter that lets the widgets TextButton.icon and ElevatedButton.icon place the label first then the icon. Is there a way or do I have to make a custom widget for this?

Example:

```
                    ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () { /* code */ },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      label: Text('Some text'),
                    )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both `icon` & `label` accepts a `Widget`. So you could do this:

```dart
ElevatedButton.icon(
  icon: Text('A'),
  label: Icon(Icons.add),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

Comment: That totally works, thank you! It makes a lot of sense if you dismiss the parameter names because both "icon" and "label" takes in a "widget".